# @Transactional is not working with Spring 6 , Hibernate 5.6 (JDK17)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I see that @Transactional is not working as expected with my class. This is the class that I have operations to deal Database operations. My application is on Spring 6, Hibernate 5.6 and JDK17. The project was working as expected with Spring 5.3 and Hibernate 5.4, problem arised when it is migrated to Spring 6. Application server is Tomee 9.x.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public abstract class NietoAbstractService<T, K extends Serializable>
        implements Serializable {

 @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 private Session getCurrentSession() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return session;
  }
}
```

Here when ever I fetch the currentSession, I am not able to fetch the session instead I had to OpenSession explicitly due to HibernateException which I was never doing in the previous version. Not sure what is changed in the newer version of spring.

As I am creating a session on demand when ever I have a db operation, it is not done in single transaction which results in issues.

```
 @Transactional
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T create(T entity)
            throws NietoException {

        T persistedEntity;
        this.cachedModel = null;
        Session session = null;
        try {
           session = this.getCurrentSession();
            K id = (K) session.save(entity);
            persistedEntity = this
                    .findById(id,session);
        } catch (NietoException | HibernateException ex) {
            throw NietoExceptionsUtils
                    .build("An error occurred persisting a new entity", ex);
        } finally {
            session.clear();
        }
        return persistedEntity;
    }

  public T findById(K id)
            throws NietoException {

        T entity = null;
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = this.getCurrentSession();
            entity = (T) session.get(this
                            .getDefinedClass(), id);
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            throw NietoExceptionsUtils
                    .build(ERROR_OCCURRED_DELETING_THE_ENTITY, ex);
        } finally {
            session.clear();
        }
        return entity;
    }
```

In the above snippet, I am facing issue while fetching persistedEntity as null as every operation is done in different session. I am able to persist on to database only when I am commiting the transaction explicitly.

Managing transaction explicitly is not a good idea because it might have impact. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Following is the applicationContext.xml file that I have set up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!-- Declare the Interceptor for i18n -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.hp.nieto.interceptors.NietoLocaleChangeIntereptor"
              p:paramName="locale" />
        <bean class="com.hp.nieto.interceptors.NietoSecurityHeadersInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- Multipart Resolver for file uploads -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver" />

    <!--Scans the classpath for annotated components @Component, @Repository,
        @Service, and @Controller -->
    <!-- Allowing annotation based Spring MVC controller declaration -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hp.nieto.*,com.opentext.asl.*" />

    <!--Activates @Required, @Autowired, @PostConstruct, @PreDestroy and @Resource -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <!-- Session Factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="com.hp.nieto.config.providers.jpa.NietoLocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files"></prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class"> -->
                <!-- com.hp.nieto.config.providers.jpa.SpringSessionContext -->
                <!-- </prop> -->
                <!-- Connection pool -->
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
                <!-- Turning on the second level cache in general -->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <!-- Turning on the query cache regions. The query and timestamp cache
                    regions will be created and used -->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <!-- Hibernate will create separate cache regions for Hibernate caching,
                    instead of trying to reuse cache regions defined elsewhere in the application -->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jakarta.cache.provider">org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jakarta.cache.uri">/assetview-cache-config.xml</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.allow_load_outside_transaction">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.hp.nieto.model.*" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.hp.nieto.config.providers.jpa.NietoDataSource">
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
                          transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
          class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!--This switches on the load-time weaving for @Configurable annotated classes -->
    <context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on"/>
</beans>
```

I have tried adding manual commiting the transaction which is a bad idea. It would be great if you can share your thoughts.

- I have tried ***hibernate***.***current_session_context_class = thread*** but it didn't help.